# Querying sequential data with date/time and text values in the same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

My data is single field, and include date, time, hour but also include data that i need.

Already query 2 keyword but the data still big and too many empty second keyword

```
SELECT Field1
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Field1 Like '*EVENT_1' Or
      Field1 Like '*DATETIME'
```

I expect the output is:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you uploading this data from somewhere into the DB, you should split so not in one column i.e. I'm not sure how in image you know 'EVENT_1 - val:10' relates to 'may/01/2019 7:00' except the row order, but even though when you select you may get the right order it may not always be the case.

Comment: The data is logging file from server & based on text.
the file is sorting base on time & event captured,
usually is easy processing in excel, but the issue now the data has 7 Million raw

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column that specifies the ordering, you really have no way to pivot the values that you want.  And even if you did, this would be rather painful to do in MS Access.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261769/how-to-update-begatt-endatt-values-by-mdb-query/56263360#56263360. This is example of establishing relationship for groups of records. The only reason this was possible is there is a field that can be used to order the records. Your data lacks this. You would have to pre-process data in Excel so the date is copied to each row below it. Then only records with value could be imported to Access.

Comment: Or instead of copying date to each row, insert a column and let Excel calculate a sequential number in that column. That can be the column to use for sorting records and VBA code extracts related data.

Comment: Criteria for limiting to "Event_1" is not correct: `LIKE 'Event_1*'`. Don't even understand how `LIKE '*DATETIME'`works.

Answer (score 0):

Start by importing your log data into Access. While doing so, tell Access to create its own Primary Key, which will be an AutoNumber:

```
[impLogData]

ID  Field1            
--  ------------------
 1    May/01/2019 7:00
 2  EVENT_0           
 3  EVENT_1 - val:10  
 4  EVENT_2           
 5  EVENT_3           
 6  EVENT_4           
 7  EVENT_5           
 8  EVENT_6           
 9    May/01/2019 8:00
10  EVENT_2           
11  EVENT_3           
12  EVENT_12          
13  EVENT_13          
14  EVENT_14          
15    May/01/2019 9:00
16  EVENT_0           
17  EVENT_1 - val:15  
18  EVENT_2
```

Create a [tblLogTime] table as

ID - Long Integer, Primary Key
logTime - Date/Time

and populate it with

```sql
INSERT INTO tblLogTime ( ID, logTime )
SELECT impLogData.ID, CDate([Field1]) AS Expr1
FROM impLogData
WHERE (((IsDate([Field1]))=True));
```

producing

```
[tblLogTime]

ID  logTime            
--  -------------------
 1  2019-05-01 07:00:00
 9  2019-05-01 08:00:00
15  2019-05-01 09:00:00
```

Then create a [tblLogEvent] table as

logTime - Date/Time
logEvent - Text(255)

and populate it with

```sql
INSERT INTO tblLogEvent ( logTime, logEvent )
SELECT DMax("logTime","tblLogTime","ID < " & [impLogData].[ID]) AS Expr1, impLogData.Field1
FROM impLogData LEFT JOIN tblLogTime ON impLogData.ID = tblLogTime.ID
WHERE (((tblLogTime.ID) Is Null));
```

producing

```
[tblLogEvent]

logTime              logEvent        
-------------------  ----------------
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_0         
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_1 - val:10
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_2         
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_3         
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_4         
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_5         
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_6         
2019-05-01 08:00:00  EVENT_2         
2019-05-01 08:00:00  EVENT_3         
2019-05-01 08:00:00  EVENT_12        
2019-05-01 08:00:00  EVENT_13        
2019-05-01 08:00:00  EVENT_14        
2019-05-01 09:00:00  EVENT_0         
2019-05-01 09:00:00  EVENT_1 - val:15
2019-05-01 09:00:00  EVENT_2
```

You can then select EVENT_1 rows using

```sql
SELECT tblLogEvent.logTime, tblLogEvent.logEvent
FROM tblLogEvent
WHERE (((tblLogEvent.logEvent) Like "EVENT_1 *"))
ORDER BY tblLogEvent.logTime;
```

producing

```
logTime              logEvent        
-------------------  ----------------
2019-05-01 07:00:00  EVENT_1 - val:10
2019-05-01 09:00:00  EVENT_1 - val:15
```